# What is the best way to create a Flutter/Firebase wrapper that auto-redirects based on auth status?

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication

I am building a flutter app with a Firebase backend. The issue is redirecting the user to the Home Screen if they are signed in and to the Auth Screens if they are signed out. When a user signs out while at the home screen, they are automatically redirected to the auth pages, however, when they sign in, the app stays on that page and I have to restart for it to go to the home screen.

This is my app structure

```
main - Splash - Wrapper - Home/Auth
```

My wrapper code is

```
    final auth = Provider.of<AuthService>(context);
     return StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: auth.user,
      builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<User?> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
      final User? user = snapshot.data;
      return user == null ? AndroidAuth() : AndroidHome();
      } else {
      return Scaffold(
        body: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
      }
     },
     );
    }
```

my main where I initialize Firebase

```
    void main() async {
     WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
     await Firebase.initializeApp();
     runApp(const MyApp());
    }
```

Material App is wrapped in multiprovider.

```
    return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    Provider<AuthService>(
      create: (_) => AuthService(),
    )
  ],
  child: MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flightbag',
    theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
    home: const AndroidSplash(),
  ),
);
```

I get auth state changes like so:

```
      Stream<User?>? get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebase);
  }
```

And create User object like :

```
      User? _userFromFirebase(auth.User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return User(user.uid, user.email);
  }
```

Please help. I have been stuck on this for days.

Comment: What is `auth.user` in your code? It seems that code is not firing when the user signs in. You should typically use `authStateChanges` to get this type of behavior as shown here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state

Comment: I use auth state changes. Just updated code on the Question.